# Pivot or Group function to merge the result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a code something as below,

```
WITH result_set 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT lt.id                       AS labTestId, 
                         lt.pass_customer_specs      AS passCustomer, 
                         lt.pass_internal_specs      AS passInternal, 
                         ltr.lab_test_measurement_id AS ltMeasurementId, 
                         ltc.compound_id             AS compoundId, 
                         lt.batch_number             AS batch_number, 
                         m.NAME                      AS NAME, 
                         ltn.id                      AS test_machine 
         FROM   lab_test lt 
                JOIN lab_test_result ltr 
                  ON ltr.lab_test_id = lt.id 
                JOIN lab_test_measurement ltm 
                  ON ltm.id = ltr.lab_test_measurement_id 
                JOIN lab_test_machine ltn 
                  ON ltn.id = ltm.lab_test_machine_id 
                JOIN lab_test_compound ltc 
                  ON ltc.compound_id = lt.lab_test_compound_id 
                JOIN compound c 
                  ON c.id = ltc.compound_id 
                JOIN measurement m 
                  ON m.id = ltm.measurement_id) 
SELECT compoundid, 
       batch_number, 
       COALESCE(Cast([1] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'MV', 
       COALESCE(Cast([2] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'MDR', 
       COALESCE(Cast([3] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'Hardness', 
       COALESCE(Cast([9] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'SPG' 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   result_set) pvt 
       PIVOT ( Min (passcustomer) 
             FOR test_machine IN ([1], 
                                  [2], 
                                  [3], 
                                  [9]) ) AS pvt 
ORDER  BY compoundid, 
          batch_number
```

which gives me something as follow,

[image: Image1]

What I am looking to do is have single Entry per batch_number and put all the 'MV', 'MDR', 'Hardness', 'SPG' on 1 line.

Comment: What if you just remove `compoundId` from the `FROM` clause (and from the `ORDER BY` clause)?

Comment: It's the same since that multiple entries are coming from lab_test_result table. Here's the Hierarchy,  For Every compound I can have multiple batch_number. For every batch_number, I can have multiple lab_test_id and for every lab_test_id, I can have multiple lab_test_results. Every lab_test_id will have only one lab_test_machine which is 'MV', 'MDR'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
WITH result_set 
     AS (SELECT DISTINCT lt.id                       AS labTestId, 
                         lt.pass_customer_specs      AS passCustomer, 
                         lt.pass_internal_specs      AS passInternal, 
                         ltr.lab_test_measurement_id AS ltMeasurementId, 
                         ltc.compound_id             AS compoundId, 
                         lt.batch_number             AS batch_number, 
                         m.NAME                      AS NAME, 
                         ltn.id                      AS test_machine 
         FROM   lab_test lt 
                JOIN lab_test_result ltr 
                  ON ltr.lab_test_id = lt.id 
                JOIN lab_test_measurement ltm 
                  ON ltm.id = ltr.lab_test_measurement_id 
                JOIN lab_test_machine ltn 
                  ON ltn.id = ltm.lab_test_machine_id 
                JOIN lab_test_compound ltc 
                  ON ltc.compound_id = lt.lab_test_compound_id 
                JOIN compound c 
                  ON c.id = ltc.compound_id 
                JOIN measurement m 
                  ON m.id = ltm.measurement_id) 
SELECT compoundid,batch_number, MAX(MV)MV, MAX(MDR)MDR, MAX(Hardness)Hardness, MAX(SPG)SPG
FROM (
SELECT compoundid, 
       batch_number, 
       COALESCE(Cast([1] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'MV', 
       COALESCE(Cast([2] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'MDR', 
       COALESCE(Cast([3] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'Hardness', 
       COALESCE(Cast([9] AS VARCHAR(1)), '-') AS 'SPG' 
FROM   (SELECT * 
        FROM   result_set) pvt 
       PIVOT ( Min (passcustomer) 
             FOR test_machine IN ([1], 
                                  [2], 
                                  [3], 
                                  [9]) ) AS pvt 
) X
GROUP BY compoundid, batch_number
ORDER  BY compoundid, batch_number
```